# Spinner setAdapter menu NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-menu

When trying to set an adapter for a spinner I created I am getting a NullPointerException

This is my code :

Menu :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_country"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_social_public"
    android:title="Country"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"/>

</menu>
```

OnCreateOptionsMenu :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_country);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)item.getActionView();
    String[] items={"Home","Search","Settings"};
    ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,items);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    return true;
}
```

Any idead why I am getting a NullPointerException ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `android:actionViewClass` to `app:actionViewClass`. You're using the support library, so you need to use the support version of those attributes. Otherwise the `MenuInflater` can't find the class you want so it throws a `NullPointerException`.